# Summary table with xForms

Tags: xpath, xforms, xforms-betterform

I have an xml like the following:

```
<table1>
    <row>
        <person>person1</person>
        <value>10</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <person>person2</person>
        <value>20</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <person>person1</person>
        <value>5</value>
    </row>
</table1>
<summaryTable>
    <row>
        <person>person1</person>
        <value_total/>
    </row>
    <row>
        <person>person2</person>
        <value_total/>
    </row>
</summaryTable>
```

With XForms 1 (there is no option to switch to XForms 2), using framework betterform, I want to calculate the values in the summary table, by doing the SUM of the rows in 'table1' that have the same person name. To do that I have the following binds:

```
<xf:bind id="bind_table1"
    nodeset="table1" repeatableElement="row">
    <xf:bind id="bind_head_table1" nodeset="head" />
    <xf:bind id="bind_row_table1" nodeset="row">
        <xf:bind id="bind_person" nodeset="person"  type="xf:string" />
        <xf:bind id="bind_value" nodeset="value"    type="xf:integer" />
    </xf:bind>
</xf:bind>
<xf:bind id="bind_summaryTable"
    nodeset="summaryTable"
    repeatableElement="row">
    <xf:bind id="bind_head_summaryTable" nodeset="head" />
    <xf:bind id="bind_row_summaryTable" nodeset="row">
        <xf:bind id="bind_person_name" nodeset="person_name" type="xf:string" readonly="true"/>
        <xf:bind id="bind_value_total" nodeset="value_total" type="xf:integer" readonly="true" calculate="SUM(//table1/row[person/text() = ../person_name/text()]/value)"/>
    </xf:bind>
</xf:bind>
```

What I want to have at the end is the value_total for person1 = 15 and value_total for person2 = 20, but using this 'calculate' expression I'm getting 'NaN'. If I replace the calculate expression to compare with a literal String like:

```
<xf:bind id="bind_value_total" nodeset="value_total" type="xf:integer" readonly="true" calculate="SUM(//table1/row[person/text() = 'person1']/value)"/>
```

then I get as value_total 15 (the sum is correctly done). So it seems that the error is in the comparison expression person/text() = ../person_name/text() . Does someone have an idea about how should be the correct expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the `context()` function in the `calculate` attribute to refer to the current node, like this:

```
<xf:bind nodeset="summaryTable/row/value_total" calculate="sum(//table1/row[person/text() = context()/../person/text()]/value)"/>
```

The `context` function gives you the current context node. If your bind references a nodeset with multiple nodes, it will be evaluated one time for every node, and that node is what `context()` returns.

It works for me with XSLTForms, maybe your version of betterForm supports it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the result is the same using context(). I'm start thinking that it's a bug in betterForm :(